# Spring Config Server JDBC Backend with custom table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to use spring config server with custom backend table, I need this as we already have a table used for something else and we want to reuse it for configuration without having to create the PROPERTIES table in all the configuration examples

Answer (score 0):

Use can use following property file where you can actually define table and selected data fields.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT KEY, VALUE from  CUSTOMER_TABLE where SOMETHING=? 
          order: 1 
  datasource:
    url: <your db url here>
    driver-class-name: <your databases driver class here>
    username: <your user to database>
    password: 
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      connection-timeout: 5000
  profiles:
    active:
    - jdbc
```

Comment: then how do you set the actual value for "SOMETHING"

Comment: you can define at Client Side

Comment: can you show me a complete working example of this, I tried but it doesn't seem to work, it seems to always expect 3 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Mention the complete SQL and make sure the `JdbcEnvironmentRepository` is not made new every time.

The sql query should be of format

```
cloud:
config:
  enabled: true
  server:
    jdbc:
      default-label: latest
      sql: SELECT [KEY], [VALUE] from Config_Parameter where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and (LABEL=? or LABEL is NULL)
```